# How can I change field values to be inserted in the asp.net membership creation

Tags: asp.net

I want to insert user name as unique mail ID and for the mail field in the registration process I want to use the same mail id to be inserted in the asp.net membership user table but by now it was creating user it's own but now I want to change it how can I achieve this ?

I am writing on page load

```
MembershipCreateStatus creatStatus;
Membership.CreateUser(RegisterUser.UserName, RegisterUser.Password, 
                      RegisterUser.UserName, RegisterUser.Question, 
                      RegisterUser.Password, 
                      true, MembershipCreateStatus.ProviderError);
                      // true, creatStatus);
```

Is it correct? But it throws error invalid argument.

What should I do for last two arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the last parameter is an out parameter.  This means that CreateUser will set the variable you specify, you can't pass in a status enumeration like you are doing there.

Instead, you have to do it like the code you commented out, except you have to specify `out creatStatus` (including the out keyword).

Second, invalid argument typically means one of the values is null.